How to get all parameters in advanced configuration for Databricks Delta Live Table pipeline?
I'd like to get list of parameters defined in Delta Live table configuration section

Using python language for Delta Live Table framework, if I know the name of parameter, I can get its value from spark session config using spark.conf.get() method as described here
I assumed the list of parameters I am looking for should be provided by
(1) spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()
or
(2) spark.sparkContext._conf.getAll().
However first option throws the security exception:
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.SparkConf. Trace:
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public org.apache.spark.SparkConf(boolean) is not whitelisted.
    at py4j.security.WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.checkConstructor(WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.java:451)

and the second one provides the list without proper config parameters defined in DLT pipeline.
Is there any way to find that?

Use the spark.conf.get() method. Here is some sample code:
sql_placeholder_code = spark.conf.get("SQL_PLACEHOLDER_CODE", "default_value")

print(f"The value of SQL_PLACEHOLDER_CODE is: {sql_placeholder_code}")

